# 2FA locks me out on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, security, two-factor-authentication

I installed and tested pam_google_authenticator on ubuntu 22.04 for ssh.
I enabled GUI 2FA by add line
"auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok" to /etc/pam.d/common-session and tested 2FA with locking screen and restarting pc.
But today when I try to code start pc it hangs at ubuntu splash screen. I have to start with usb drive then mount boot disk and remove this line above in order to to boot.
Is this normal? Should I just not use 2FA in gnome GUI?